# Not Responding when using PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtwidgets

I just began to learn PyQt5 in python and the window which opens becomes not responding[image]

```
import sys
import PyQt5
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore
x=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
y=QtWidgets.QWidget()
y.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following line to the end of your code:

```
sys.exit(x.exec_())
```

I would also recommend following a tutorial such as this one as PyQt does have a framework which needs to be followed closely. (http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/firstprograms/)